# Samba (smbd) - Share a drive partition

Tags: samba, gparted, shared-folders

I've made a partition on my linux (home)server's hard drive with the size of 15000MiB. It shows up as /dev/sda3 on GParted. I've tried everything to try and get just the drive mounted as a samba shared folder; Any insights?

I'm looking to only allow users with the username NAS and password NAS to access it. Can someone help me with some commands?

For now, I've deleted Samba and Samba-common, deleted the files with it, and reinstalled both. Just to start clean.

Sincerely,
Anna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a folder and mount the partition to the folder. The folder is, what you share with Samba. Sharing the folder means to share the contents of the folder, here it will be the whole partition which is mounted to the folder.

Example:
We create a folder in our /home-directory

```
mkdir ~/share
```

Now we have to take care that the partition is mounted to the folder `~/share` either during
startup or whenever the drive is plugged in for the case we use an external drive.
We do that with adding a line to the file `/etc/fstab`

```
/dev/sda3  ~/share  ext3  rw,nofail 0  2
```

You have to adapt this line to your needs, (foldername, used filesystem). The `nofail-option`
is important if you use an external drive, using this option the system will not complain during startup if the drive is not plugged.

Instead of `/dev/sda3` you may use the UUID of the partition, then you have to check the UUID first with `sudo blkid`, look up for the desired partition and change `/dev/sda3` to `UUID=6819ff77-a109-4b82-a577-2cea9f560195`.
Remind that the number here is just an example and you have to use the number you got from `blkid`.
Also remind to remove the double-quotes if you copy/paste from terminal.
Using UUID the fstabline would look like this:

```
UUID=6819ff77-a109-4b82-a577-2cea9f560195   ~/share  ext3  rw.nofail 0  2
```

So now we know how it works and we go to edit the fstab-file in terminal:

```
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak
```

This creates a backup of the original file. `/etc/fstab` is an important system-file, so we 
create a backup first for the case something goes wrong during editing. Now open the file for 
editing:

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

Add the fstab-line and leave the editor with `Ctrl+C` and `y`.

You have to adpat the section for your share in the Samba-configuration-file `/etc/samba/smb.conf`.
Following our example it should look like this:

```
# In this section we share a folder which contains a partition
[share]
    comment = share a whole partition
    path = ~/share
    browsable = yes
    guest ok = yes
    read only = no
    create mask = 0777
```

The first line is only a comment-line. the second line defines the name of the share, it
makes sense to give the share the same name as the shared folder.
In the line `comment =` you may enter what you want as value. Really important is the forth line
with `path =` because here we define the folder which is shared. 
The rest of this example I just copied from my own configuration file and you will have to adapt it
to fit your needs.

Note1:

You could create the folder you want to share anywhere in your file-system but if you create the folder
somewhere else than in your home-directory you will get problems with ownership and permissions.
It would be possible to solve that with chown-command but make things more complicated for you, so the best
is to create the folder you want to share in your home-directory as we did in this small example.

Note2:

If something went wrong while editing the ftsab-file you can restore the original file with `sudo cp -f /etc/fstab.bak /etc/fstab`. This will not remove the backup-file, it will just restore the original file leaving the backup-file untouched. In case the system fails to boot because you damaged the fstab-file during edit, you can drop to a root-shell and use this command to restore the original file, just don't need `sudo` then...

Comment: That absolutely did the trick! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a filesystem on /dev/sda3 first.
For example

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda3
```

Then mount it to a mountpoint. 
Only then you can configure samba to make this directory available to others

Comment: As far as I remember, i've formatted it as Ext4. Does it still require a filesystem creation? Also, can I just enter /dev/sda3 in the Samba GUI? I can't see drives in PCmanFM on Lubuntu.

Comment: And now Nautilus says /media/server/ce6b684b-b251-496a-80c8-a8000b6c325d is what sda3 is. I tried mounting sda in a samba thing but can't figure it out.

Comment: When you have a filesystem on it and it is mounted to a mountpoint, you enter that mountpoint into samba config file. You don't enter /dev/something to samba config.